# problem with imageview

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I am trying to do a drag and drop application. For that I first created a `main.xml` with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
<com.hide.move.MyImageView
android:id="@+id/Image1"
android:src="@drawable/sarathphoto7"
android:layout_weight="50" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

 <com.hide.move.MyImageView
android:id="@+id/Image2"
android:src="@drawable/sarathphoto6"
android:layout_weight="50" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200px"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and created a Java file to view the `main.xml` content.

```
public class hidenmove extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}.
```

but I am getting

Comment: It will be great to know what exactly you are getting.

Comment: i am getting exception.Fatal exception

Comment: Sarath: You should state that in your question. As well as the exception name, stacktrace excerpt and other information that can help others puzzle out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First note that drag and drop feature is included in  **API level 11**.

Check this : [Dragging and Dropping](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: sharma....thanks....but the code i had written above for only display the imageview content.Pls check dat and tell me whats the problem of my code..

Comment: Are you creating a class MyImageView in your package(com.hide.move) that extends ImageView or simply View..?

Comment: Note that referring to an external resource without including the relevant content here, too, is bad. It may be easier to churn out answers by the dozens by just saying »Check this: <link>« but it's not very helpful.

Comment: i read an article about drag and drop.Based on that concept i am creating my application.now i understand my problem.i didn't created any class named ImageView. Million thanks buddy.One more doupt.Why can't i simply use <Imageview> instead of <come.hide.move.ImageView>?\